# How to append an object to a list within a class (python)

Tags: python

I have a class called car and a list called cars. Every time I create an instance of a car I want it to get added to the cars list, without typing "cars.append(car1)" etc.. every time I create an instance of a car object. Is there a way to do it inside the class?

```
cars = []


class car:

    def __init__(self, make, model, year, colour, kilometers, pre_owned, price):
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.year = year
        self.colour = colour
        self.kilometers = kilometers
        self.pre_owned = pre_owned
        self.price = price

        #code that adds car instance to cars list


car1 = car("Mazda", "3", 2005, "Orange", 200000, True, 4000)
car2 = car("Fiat", "500", 2012, "White", 100000, True, 8000)
car3 = car("Dodge", "Ram", 2010, "Black", 130000, True, 10000)
car4 = car("Mini", "Cooper", 2019, "Grey", 1000, True, 18000)
```

Comment: `cars.append(self)` inside `__init__`?

Comment: @NickSciarretta: You also need to understand why that worked. Please read https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/classes.html

Comment: I would also say I think it makes more sense to put `cars` inside the class

Comment: I am curious as to why you don't want to call `cars.append()`. What is your reason?

Answer (score 1):

When Python class instance is created, it calls `__init__` method. You can leverage this behavior for your need as commented by @Chris like this.

```
cars = []


class car:

    def __init__(self, make, model, year, colour, kilometers, pre_owned, price):
        cars.append(self)
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cars.append(self)
```

Put it inside init at the end

Answer (score 0):

Use the init method as a class and append it inside .

class car:

```
def __init__(self, make, model, year, color, kilometers, pre_owned, price):
    cars.append(self)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your list is out of the class. You should declare each of your cars like this :

```
cars += [car("Mazda", "3", 2005, "Orange", 200000, True, 4000)]
```

Answer (score 0):

All the proposed answers work, but they are not object oriented solutions.

Following the object oriented paradigm, classes should be self contained, such that you can reuse them in other parts of the project and maintain them independently.

Thus, you should not be using the `cars` list inside the `Car` class like that.

If in your modelling there must always be a list of cars, you should create the list as a static attribute of the `Car` class and operate it from there. This ensures that anywhere the class is imported would contain the `cars` list.

Also, to follow pep8, [class names should follow the CapWords convetions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names).

```
class Car:

    cars = []

    def __init__(self, make, model, year, colour, kilometers, pre_owned, price):
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.year = year
        self.colour = colour
        self.kilometers = kilometers
        self.pre_owned = pre_owned
        self.price = price

        Car.cars.append(self)


car1 = Car("Mazda", "3", 2005, "Orange", 200000, True, 4000)
car2 = Car("Fiat", "500", 2012, "White", 100000, True, 8000)
car3 = Car("Dodge", "Ram", 2010, "Black", 130000, True, 10000)
car4 = Car("Mini", "Cooper", 2019, "Grey", 1000, True, 18000)

[print(my_car.make) for my_car in Car.cars]
```

**However**, If you want to be even more strict, the `Car` class should not contain a `cars` list, as it does not philosophically makes sense for a car to have that. In this case, I am afraid the best alternative is to always call the `cars.append(Car(...))`.